# Separately controlling positioning of y-axis line and y-axis labels

Tags: d3.js, axis, axis-labels, yaxis

I am creating a bar chart using d3. The bar chart accepts negative values. The chart I am creating is [based on this chart here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2368837), and mostly have similar setup.

The change I like to make is shift the text labels of the y-axis to the absolute left of the chart, but keep the y-axis line at its original spot.

From the above link, the following are the lines of code to render the y-axis (they are at the bottom of the page, almost the last thing of the code)

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);
```

Now, if I adjust the above `translate` line to the following

```
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
```

then BOTH the axis line AND the labels will be left aligned. I would like to keep the axis line at its position but move all the labels to the left.

How can I do that?

PS. A solution I thought about is to create second y-axis. The first y-axis is hidden with the labels shown, and is displayed to the left. The second y-axis is shown, but the labels are hidden, and is at the center. However, I do not like this solution, I do not think it is very clean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just increase the tick padding:

```
.tickPadding(width/2 - margin.left);
```

Comment: PS: I personally don't like writing short answers like that, I normally share an updated bl.ocks so OPs can see the solution working, but blockbuilder (that we use to change bl.ocks codes) has a bug since yesterday.

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect.